# What is the timing arc in vlsi?

Tags: vlsi

What is the timing arc? STA and Design compiler.
When I was finding the arc at internet, just it written like this.
Timing arc is the timing of data  signal travelling ff to ff.
Is this some kind of timing reports as text? Or something like a db? What is this? Also where does this used for what?
Is this helps to something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one. I think this is the best solution for this case http://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2013/07/timing-arcs.html

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of the content of the link. It is required to do so in the guidelines. The reasons for this are that the link could die, and that people can get a rough(fast) overview on site, without following links.

Answer (score -1):

timing arc is  a timing path from any input to any output